# How does PuLP (Linear Programming) LpMaximize pick the Optimal Solution?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm using PuLP in Python and maximizing a decision variable using LpMaximize. Let's say I have several combinations with certain points for each combination. The decision variable in this case is "points" as points are what I'm trying to maximize. My intended objective of this exercise is to find the combinations with highest points. My code for this:

```
prob = LpProblem("Allocation",LpMaximize)

alloc_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Allocation",combinations,0,1,LpBinary)

prob += lpSum(binary.loc[i]["points"]*alloc_vars[i] for i in combinations)

for j in vendors:
prob += lpSum([alloc_vars[i]*binary.loc[i][j] for i in combinations]) == 1

#"binary" is a matrix file/dataframe that's commonly used in PuLP solver

prob.solve()
print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])

var_output = []
for i in alloc_vars:
for j in vendors:
    var_output += [{
        'Vendor': j,
        'Combination': i,
        'Allocation': alloc_vars[i].varValue*binary.loc[i][j],
    }]

[i for i in var_output if i['Allocation']==1]

value(prob.objective)

selected_combinations = set([i['Combination'] for i in var_output if i['Allocation']==1])
```

Sample input: (this is jut dummy data)

```
| Combination | Vendor 1 | Vendor 2 | Vendor 3 | Vendor 4 | Points |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D | 
|   Comb1     |     A    |          |          |          |   73   |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0 |
|   Comb2     |     B    |          |          |          |   54   |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0 |  
|   Comb3     |     C    |          |          |          |   47   |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0 |
|   Comb4     |     D    |          |          |          |   89   |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1 |
|   Comb5     |     A    |     B    |          |          |   73   |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0 |
|   Comb6     |     B    |     A    |          |          |   -43  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0 |
|   Comb7     |     D    |     C    |   A      |          |   111  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1 |
...
...
...
```

As output I get combinations with maximum points. I'm not sure how exactly these combinations are selected though. As a corner case, I had an input dataframe with all the combinations having 0 points, but still got some combinations after running PuLP solver. So this got me wondering, how does PuLP find which combination will give the maximum points?

Comment: "How" may not be the best question.  IMHO a better question is "why does it pick the given solution". That is completely determined by the model you feed it. I.e. the objective and the constraints.

Comment: If your question is 'how does pulp find an optimal solution', then the answer, so far as I know, is an implementation of the simplex alogorithm - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm, with some form of branch-and-bound for binary variables. If you're question is how is a particular solution chosen from many of the equally optimal solutions (in problems where optimal solution is non-unique), then I think effecively it is random. It might be 'repeatable' but there is no need for it to be. If you care between these equally optimal solutions you should modify your objective function.